# Difference between two dates in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sql-date-functions

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION diff(d1 date,d2 date) RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN
IF d1 = NULL THEN
RETURN SELECT extract(year from age(current_date,d2));
ELSE
RETURN SELECT extract(year from age(d1,d2));
END IF;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

My requirement is to find the difference between two dates in years. So, I write the above function. Here, if d1 is NULL then it is assigned with current date. But, it produce error like as shown below.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: SELECT  SELECT extract(year from age(current_date, $1 ))
QUERY:  SELECT  SELECT extract(year from age(current_date, $1 ))
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "diff" near line 4
```

Does any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: did you try removing SELECT ? `RETURN extract(year from age(d1,d2));`

Comment: Other than Jay's comment, another potential problem might be that `AGE()` is not returning a date type which `extract()` can handle.

Comment: @JayKumarR  As per your suggestion, the function created successfully. But, it doesn't give the expected output. If d1 is null, it returns NULL as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
date_part('year',age(coalesce(d1,current_date), d2))::int;
```

`age(d1,d2)` function returns the number of years, months, and days between two dates in following format:

```
xxx year(s) xxx mon(s) xxx day(s).
```

from this output using `date_part()` to pick the only the year difference. and also no need to put if statement to handle `NULL` as I have added `coalesece` which returns first `NON Null` value, So if `d1` is `NULL` it return `cuurent_date`

Function Structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION diff(d1 date,d2 date) RETURNS int AS $$
BEGIN

 RETURN date_part('year',age(coalesce(d1,current_date), d2))::int;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Function Call:

```
select * from diff(null,'2010-04-01');
select * from diff('2012-10-01','2010-04-01');
```

Comment: It shows error like 'ERROR:  mismatched parentheses at or near ")"
LINE 7: RETURN date_part('year',age(d1,current_date), d2))::int;
                                                         ^

Comment: share the function you have created.

Comment: This is working for mine. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: `CREATE FUNCTION diff(d1 date,d2 date) RETURNS int AS $$        
    BEGIN
    IF d1 = NULL THEN
    RETURN extract(year from age(current_date,d2));
    ELSE
    RETURN extract(year from age(d1,d2));
    END IF;
    END
    $$ language plpgsql;`

Comment: @mrg: Create the function as in answer and No need to check for `NULL` value.